# How to fill a fillable pdf from cocoa touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pdf

I was wondering if anyone had seen an example of using cocoa touch to complete a fillable pdf form?  So far I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches for doing this.!

1.) Server Approach

Have your inputs in xib and send the details to the server to create pdf using the form data. There are several pdf generation javascripts available.

2.) Using native approach

check this link http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page